# Conflicting types and previous declaration of function?

Tags: c

While using make to compile an OS I've got a weird error from make that I don't understand.

from make:

```
source/paging.c:179:6: error: conflicting types for ‘page_fault’
headers/paging.h:68:6: note: previous declaration of ‘page_fault’ was here
make: *** [obj/paging.o] Error 1
```

The function(s) in question are the ones that follow. I haven't included the whole file of paging.c as it is very big, same goes for paging.h tbh, but if you want to see the header file I will post the rest.

paging.c:

```
....
....
void page_fault(registers_t regs)
{
// A page fault has occurred.
// The faulting address is stored in the CR2 register.
u32int faulting_address;
asm volatile("mov %%cr2, %0" : "=r" (faulting_address));

// The error code gives us details of what happened.
int present   = !(regs.err_code & 0x1); // Page not present
int rw = regs.err_code & 0x2;           // Write operation?
int us = regs.err_code & 0x4;           // Processor was in user-mode?
int reserved = regs.err_code & 0x8;     // Overwritten CPU-reserved bits of page entry?
int id = regs.err_code & 0x10;          // Caused by an instruction fetch?

// Output an error message.
monitor_write("Page fault! ( ");
if (present) {monitor_write("present ");}
if (rw) {monitor_write("read-only ");}
if (us) {monitor_write("user-mode ");}
if (reserved) {monitor_write("reserved ");}
monitor_write(") at 0x");
monitor_write_hex(faulting_address);
monitor_write("\n");
PANIC("Page fault");
}
```

paging.h:

```
....
....
void page_fault(registers_t *regs);
....
....
```

NOTE: This is from a tutorial ( so it should be working, but I have come into a problem with the provided source code before where one function wasn't spelt properly ).

Any idea's why make is complaining?

Thanks.

make errors without *:

```
obj/interrupt.o: In function `isr_common_stub':
asem/interrupt.s:(.text+0x1c9): undefined reference to `isr_handler'
obj/interrupt.o: In function `irq_common_stub':
asem/interrupt.s:(.text+0x1ee): undefined reference to `irq_handler'
obj/main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `placement_address'
obj/descriptor_tables.o: In function `init_descriptor_tables':
descriptor_tables.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `interrupt_handlers'
obj/timer.o: In function `init_timer':
timer.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `register_interrupt_handler'
obj/paging.o: In function `initialise_paging':
paging.c:(.text+0x298): undefined reference to `kmalloc'
paging.c:(.text+0x2cc): undefined reference to `kmalloc_a'
paging.c:(.text+0x328): undefined reference to `placement_address'
paging.c:(.text+0x341): undefined reference to `register_interrupt_handler'
obj/paging.o: In function `get_page':
paging.c:(.text+0x3da): undefined reference to `kmalloc_ap'
obj/initrd.o: In function `initialise_initrd':
initrd.c:(.text+0x1f1): undefined reference to `kmalloc'
initrd.c:(.text+0x2f5): undefined reference to `kmalloc'
initrd.c:(.text+0x402): undefined reference to `kmalloc'
obj/task.o: In function `initialise_tasking':
task.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `kmalloc'
task.c:(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to `kmalloc_a'
obj/task.o: In function `fork':
task.c:(.text+0x2b3): undefined reference to `clone_directory'
task.c:(.text+0x2c2): undefined reference to `kmalloc'
task.c:(.text+0x314): undefined reference to `kmalloc_a'
obj/syscall.o: In function `initialise_syscalls':
syscall.c:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `register_interrupt_handler'
make: *** [kern/kernel] Error 1
```

interrupt.s:

```
....
; In isr.c
extern irq_handler
....
....
; In isr.c
extern isr_handler
```

main.c:
    ....
    extern u32int placement_address;
    ....

descriptor_tables.c:

```
void init_descriptor_tables()
{

// Initialise the global descriptor table.
init_gdt();
// Initialise the interrupt descriptor table.
init_idt();
// Nullify all the interrupt handlers.
memset(&interrupt_handlers, 0, sizeof(isr_t)*256);
}
```

timer.c:

```
void init_timer(u32int frequency)
{
// Firstly, register our timer callback.
register_interrupt_handler(IRQ0, &timer_callback);

// The value we send to the PIT is the value to divide it's input clock
// (1193180 Hz) by, to get our required frequency. Important to note is
// that the divisor must be small enough to fit into 16-bits.
u32int divisor = 1193180 / frequency;

// Send the command byte.
outb(0x43, 0x36);

// Divisor has to be sent byte-wise, so split here into upper/lower bytes.
u8int l = (u8int)(divisor & 0xFF);
u8int h = (u8int)( (divisor>>8) & 0xFF );

// Send the frequency divisor.
outb(0x40, l);
outb(0x40, h);
}
```

paging.c:

```
....
void initialise_paging()
{
// The size of physical memory. For the moment we 
// assume it is 16MB big.
u32int mem_end_page = 0x1000000;

nframes = mem_end_page / 0x1000;
frames = (u32int*)kmalloc(INDEX_FROM_BIT(nframes));
memset(frames, 0, INDEX_FROM_BIT(nframes));

// Let's make a page directory.
kernel_directory = (page_directory_t*)kmalloc_a(sizeof(page_directory_t));
current_directory = kernel_directory;

// We need to identity map (phys addr = virt addr) from
// 0x0 to the end of used memory, so we can access this
// transparently, as if paging wasn't enabled.
// NOTE that we use a while loop here deliberately.
// inside the loop body we actually change placement_address
// by calling kmalloc(). A while loop causes this to be
// computed on-the-fly rather than once at the start.
int i = 0;
while (i < placement_address)
{
    // Kernel code is readable but not writeable from userspace.
    alloc_frame( get_page(i, 1, kernel_directory), 0, 0);
    i += 0x1000;
}
// Before we enable paging, we must register our page fault handler.
register_interrupt_handler(14, page_fault);

// Now, enable paging!
switch_page_directory(kernel_directory);
}
```

Comment: Those are linker errors, some libraries or object files are missing from a command line. The compilation itself seems to have completed fine.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: @EdS. - I have done that with everything suggested :L

Comment: So those errors did not come about as a result of the minor change that we suggested.  They were probably there are already, but since you had a compilation error that was shown first and the linker never got involved.  Since I have to guess, I am going to say that you need to link to a library (or more than one) and you haven't done so, hence the "undefined reference to <every function ever called>" errors. Or perhaps you are mixing C runtimes.

Comment: I'd decided to have a go at compiling all the provided tutorial source code ( also had a look in the paging.c/.h file and found that both had the * in the page_fault function ) but I still have the same error in that? Even though the original developer managed to get a linked kernel file out of the code?

Answer (score 4):

You have two differing signatures for a function with the same name.  Note that the first declaration takes a `registers_t`, but the second takes a `registers_t*`.

```
/* paging.h */
void page_fault(registers_t *regs);

/* paging.c */
void page_fault(registers_t regs)
```

The function signature in `paging.c` is correct per the usage of the variable `regs`, so change the declaration in the `.h` file to match.

It really stinks, but I have run into problems like this in distributed source code before (especially in school...).  Not sure how code that won't even compile can make it out into the wild like this, but it happens.

Comment: so what your saying is, remove the * from paging.h? or add it to paging.c?

Comment: Yes, change the signature in `paging.h` to match the one in `paging.c` (i.e., remove the `*`).  A function's signature includes it's return type, it's name, and any arguments it takes.  For example, this is a function signature: `int some_func(char *c)`

Comment: that's now made make give me an undefined reference to pretty much all functions in paging.c ( despite obviously giving the right references ) XD

Comment: Well are there places where that function is being called with a pointer argument?  Those would need to be fixed too.  Is that code part of a library which you are compiling and feeding to another project?  It's really hard to answer without more detail.

Comment: As far as I can remember that is the only file I added the arguments to the function. There is only one other place I found that calls the page_fault function and thats  register_interrupt_handler(14, page_fault); which is in the same file.

Comment: This `register_interrupt_handler(14, page_fault)` wouldn't cause it.  Can you post the *exact* error and the line(s) where it occurs please?

Comment: @JamieEdwards No, he means _after_ the change.

Comment: There is a lot of code to post, and tbh it's mostly unrelated to the page_fault function ( despite a few initialising functions i.e. initialise_paging ( ... ) ).

Answer (score 2):

The function signatures don't match:

Declaration in `.h` file:

```
void page_fault(registers_t *regs)
```

Definition in `.c` file:

```
void page_fault(registers_t regs)
```

Correct the signature in header file to match the one in the `.c` file (i.e. remove the `*` from `paging.h`).

Comment: doing this has given me this error and that is for every err_code in this function: source/paging.c:191:18: error: request for member ‘err_code’ in something not a structure or union

Comment: Did you remove the `*` from the `paging.h` header file?